# Adding the ordinal indicator to a date

Tags: r

I would like to know if there is a simple way to format date with suffix on the day.

I created a function in case of:

```
add.suffix <- function (x) if(day(x) %in% c(1, 21, 31)) { paste0(day(x), "st", format(x, "%B %Y"))
  } else if (day(x) %in% c(2, 22)){ paste0(day(x), "nd ", format(x, "%B %Y"))
  } else paste0(day(x), "th ", format(x, "%B %Y"))

add.suffix(Sys.Date())
```

I would like as well to convert back that character in POSIXlt.

Comment: It appears you are using `lubridate` in which case try `dmy(add.suffix(Sys.Date()))`

Comment: thanks, I am effectively using lubridate, dmy(add.suffix(Sys.Date())) give me back an error. The ordinal indicator prevent to recognise the format as date.

Comment: Strange, it works perfectly for me.  Can you paste the actual error in your question?

Comment: Sorry, it works perfectly. I had forget I changed the output format to day month, without year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method, if you are using `lubridate`, is the function `dmy`.

```
dmy(add.suffix(Sys.Date()))
```

Answer (score 0):

These do not use any packages.  The examples all use this input:

```
x <- "9th November 2015"
```

**1)** Remove `nd` and `th` and convert the remainder to `"Date"` class and then `"POSIXlt"`:

```
as.POSIXlt(as.Date(sub("nd|th", "", x), "%d %B %Y"))
[1] "2015-11-09 UTC"
```

**2)** This tries it with both `th` and `nd` and takes whichever works:

```
as.POSIXlt(na.omit(c(as.Date(x, "%dth %B %Y"), as.Date(x, "%nd %B %Y"))))
```

**3)** This is similar to the (2) but uses `Filter`, `Negate` and `lapply` so that we can place the alternate formats in a vector:

```
fmts <- c("%dth %B %Y", "%dnd %B %Y")
as.POSIXlt(Filter(Negate(is.na), lapply(fmts, as.Date, x = x))[[1]])
```

You might prefer to just convert this to `"Date"` class rather than `"POSIXlt"` since it is only a date.  Just omit the `as.POSIXlt` part in any of the above approaches.